# observer iphone for view controllers

Tags: iphone, tabs, observer-pattern, navigationcontroller

Is there any way to to check the current navigation controller or the view controller currently visible in application delegate method.

I want to create an Observer in application delegate that observes the controller being pushed and pop from the stack so that i could display the required tab bar controller. Basically my app have more than one tab bar controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `NSNotification` instances when your view controller stack changes its state. Google has lots of examples and explanations of this class ([for example](http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2009/02/nsnotifications-broadcasting-mechanism.html)).